# grom can not create to database

Tags: go, go-gorm

I use "gorm.io/gorm"
This is my struct

```
type PodPort struct {
    ID       uint   `gorm:"primaryKey;not null;AUTO_INCREMENT" json:"omitempty"`
    Port     int32  `json:"port"`
    Protocol string `json:"protocol"`
}

type PodEnv struct {
    ID       uint64 `gorm:"primaryKey;not null;AUTO_INCREMENT" json:"id,omitempty"`
    EnvKey   string `json:"env_key"`
    EnvValue string `json:"env_value"`
}

type Pod struct {
    PodID            uint64    `gorm:"unique;primaryKey;not null" json:"pod_id"`
    PodName          string    `gorm:"unique;not null" json:"pod_name"`
    PodNameSpace     string    `json:"pod_namespace"`
    PodTeamID        int64     `json:"pod_team_id"`
    PodMaxCpuUsage   float64   `json:"pod_max_cpu_usage"`
    PodMinCpuUsage   float64   `json:"pod_min_cpu_usage"`
    PodMaxMemUsage   float64   `json:"pod_max_mem_usage"`
    PodMinMemUsage   float64   `json:"pod_min_mem_usage"`
    PodPorts         []PodPort `gorm:"foreignKey:ID" json:"pod_ports"`
    PodEnvs          []PodEnv  `gorm:"foreignKey:ID" json:"pod_envs"`
    Image            string    `gorm:"not null" json:"image"`
    PodPullPolicy    string    `gorm:"default:'if_not_present'" json:"pod_pull_policy"`
    PodRestartPolicy string    `gorm:"default:'always'" json:"pod_restart_policy"`
    PodDeployType    string    `json:"pod_deploy_type"`
    Replicas         int32     `json:"replicas"`
}
```

I use db.Create(&pod) and there is no error

```
p := Pod{
        PodName: "mmm",
        PodEnvs: []PodEnv{
            {EnvKey: "key1", EnvValue: "value1"},
            {EnvKey: "key2", EnvValue: "value2"},
        },
    }
    log.Println(Db.Create(&p).Error)
```

But it just have one record in my sql, only key1.

```
mysql> select * from pod_envs;
+----+---------+-----------+
| id | env_key | env_value |
+----+---------+-----------+
|  1 | app     | test      |
|  2 | app     | test      |
|  3 | key1    | value1    |
+----+---------+-----------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I think that my database should have two pod_env records.

Comment: my gorm config is here:
Db, err = gorm.Open(mysql.Open(dsn), &gorm.Config{
  SkipDefaultTransaction: true,
 })

Answer (score 0):

I have get the current answer! I think it is basic knowledge in sql.

I must create a filed in my association table such as PodID in table `pod_envs` and the current struct is here:

```
type PodEnv struct {
ID       uint64 `gorm:"primaryKey;not null;AUTO_INCREMENT" json:"id,omitempty"`
PodID    uint64
EnvKey   string `json:"env_key"`
EnvValue string `json:"env_value"`}
```

The pod's filed have some change:`foreignKey` is the association table's filed and the `references` is present table's filed and the value is the same.

```
    PodEnvs          []PodEnv  `gorm:"foreignKey:pod_id;references:pod_id" json:"pod_envs"`
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).